# Linux mint- Black Screen instead of Login screen when 2nd monitor is disconnected

Tags: linux, linux-mint, multi-monitor

I have a dual boot installation alongside Windows 10 and have upgraded to Mint 17.2 (Tina). I used my 2nd monitor ViewSonic with my LapTop (HP Zbook 15), which is not the primary one. My laptop monitor is the primary one.
However, If I have to remove the 2nd monitor, and boot the system, instead of the login screen, there would be a black screen. Even if I connect the 2nd monitor again, it still resides black.
However, typing my password (blindly) would do the login and the main screen displays and work goes normally.
However, If I suspend the laptop and wake it up, it would show the login screen in a normal way.
I want to have a login screen on my laptop monitor is 2nd monitor is disconnected before booting the machine. How can I solve this?

Thanks a bunch.